# How to fix libtool: undefined symbols not allowed in x86_64-pc-msys shared

Tags: msys2, libtool

I am trying to build heimdal package for msys2. To my dismay, during linking of the first constituent library, roken, dlls fail to be built, and that causes sort of a chain reaction further on.

The only message i get is:

> libtool: undefined symbols not allowed in x86_64-pc-msys shared ... only static will be built

however, there is no information provided on what symbols are undefined. How can i find that out?

If i turn on output of commands wuth `make V=1` i get libtool command that links from a large numbert of .lo files. If i try to run `gcc` over them (copying command from there), it does not recognize them as anything.

I am trying to follow instructions as outlined in [msys2 package build script for heimdal](https://github.com/msys2/MSYS2-packages/blob/master/heimdal/PKGBUILD).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On Windows building a shared library while allowing undefined symbols is not allowed.

Try to build with the `-Wl,-no-undefined` linker flag, for example by adding `LDFLAGS="-Wl,-no-undefined"` to the `./configure` command.

If that didn't work try this after `./configure` and before `make`:

```
sed -i.bak -e "s/\(allow_undefined=\)yes/\1no/" libtool
```

If you already had a failed build earlier you should also clean up any `.la` files like this before running `make` again:

```
rm $(find -name '*.la')
```